# I have to send emails taking data from some columns. If the email is repeated I would like to send only one email with the values from the other cells

Tags: google-apps-script

Note: I am using Google Apps Script for my script.

I have columns A, B, and C with data to send to the emails from Column D (row by row). I have sorted the list alphabetically and some of the addresses are repeated.

Right now my code sends one email per each address in column D but this means that if the value is repeated, the person will get multiple emails.

If the record is repeated, How do I send only one message containing the respective values from columns A, B, and C?

First Name     Last Name         User Email                    Manager Email

Name 1         Last Name 1       user1@domain.com      manager1@domain.com

**Name 2        Last Name 2      user2@domain.com**   **manager2@domain.com**

**Name 3        Last Name 3      user3@domain.com**   **manager2@domain.com**

**Name 4        Last Name 4      user4@domain.com**   **manager2@domain.com**

Name 5         Last Name 5       user5@domain.com      manager3@domain.com

The above table shows that **manager2@domain.com** is repeated three times on the list. I would like to avoid sending multiple emails to the same manager and just send one message containing the values from the other columns.

e.g.

To: manager2@domain.com
Subject: Report

--------------------------------------------------

Good day,

The following people...

Name 2 Last Name 2 with email user2@domain.com

Name 3 Last Name 3 with email user3@domain.com

Name 4 Last Name 4 with email user4@domain.com

...

--------------------------------------------------

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

I find that using objects is a great way to group information.

```
function concatColumn() {
  var mgrcol=4;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var mgrA=[];
  var html='';
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(mgrA.indexOf(vA[i][3])==-1) {
      mgrA.push(vA[i][3]); 
    }
  }
  var mgrObj={}
  for(var i=0;i<mgrA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
      if(mgrA[i]==vA[j][3]){
        if(mgrObj.hasOwnProperty(mgrA[i])) {
          mgrObj[mgrA[i]]+=Utilities.formatString('~~~FirstName: %s<br />LastName: %s<br />UserEmail: %s',vA[j][0],vA[j][1],vA[j][2]);
        }else{
          mgrObj[mgrA[i]]=Utilities.formatString('FirstName: %s<br />LastName: %s<br />UserEmail: %s',vA[j][0],vA[j][1],vA[j][2]);
        }                                               
      } 
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<mgrA.length;i++) {
    var tA=mgrObj[mgrA[i]].split('~~~');
    var s='User Information<br /></br />';
    for(var j=0;j<tA.length;j++) {
      s+=tA[j].toString() + '<br />'; 
    }
    s+='<hr widht="100" />';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(mgrA[i], 'User Names and Emails', null, {htmlBody:s})
    //html+=Utilities.formatString('Email Recipient: <strong>%s</strong><br />',mgrA[i]) + s;//debug 
  }
  //var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);//debug
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Emails');//debug
}
```

The last few commented out lines are used for creating a replica of the email to display on a dialog in order to debug the script.

Comment: Hi @Cooper,
I've trying to implement this one to my problem, but I can only get an identifier key by considering data from two columns (itemCode and version). Here, we have the email address. How would I go about considering these two columns as identifier key instead? Thanks a million - once again!

Comment: If I understand your problem, I think I would have use the email as the identifer and I would have put all of the information I need for each row into the array as an object.

Comment: Why do I have a TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined? if(productObj.hasOwnProperty(productList[i])) {
          productObj[productList[i]]+=Utilities.formatString('~~~%s%s%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }else{
          productObj[productList[i]]=Utilities.formatString('%s%s%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }                                               
      } 
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    var tA=productObj[productList[i]].split('~~~');

Comment: If you want a tool to help you Copy and Redact CSV data that you can easily post into your SO questions. Here's a link: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/so-utilities/csv-utility .  Send me some data and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Cooper, I have a question on this. I am planning to utilize this script. If I have added another column for example here - column 5 for Email Sent. At the end of the code, I would like to post "Yes" after email is sent. After GmailApp...} sh.getRange(i,5).setValue("Yes")...Is this correct? For my actual data, somehow it only posts one Yes at row 6 and all others are blank.

Comment: No. That won't work.  I think you would have to collect the rownumbers in mgrObj