# Sending a single email from sheets instead of multiple for the same person

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a simple script which loops through my data table and if the value of a column M is greater than X then it sends an email. This works perfectly fine however I am trying to make it a little smarter.  As it stands a person will get an email per row and the data is such that a person could have any number of rows assigned to them and I would like to send just one email per person (col L) which contains all the row data for that person.

I'm very much a novice when it comes to this but what I believe I need to do is something along the lines of creating an empty array such as "peopleToMail" and push each email address into that, if one already exists in the array then keep adding rows of data to it, else send the mail and carry on the loop.  At least that kinda makes sense in my head but i have no idea how to execute it. I've been trying for the past 4 hours and realise my lack of knowledge has beaten me.

```
    function sendEmailsMonday() {
  const sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data"); //Sheet containing my dataset
  const data = sSheet.getRange(2, 1, sSheet.getLastRow(), sSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //get the values from the table, without the header

//  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('chaser');
//  const html4email = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getAs(contentType);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // Each column in the table


    var row = data[i];

    if(row[12] > 12) {  // If the value of column 12 is greater than X then send an email
      var message = "This is where my message will go relating to " + row[1] + '\n\n' + "sign off text here";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[11],"Subject title goes here", message); // Address, subject and message body.  Look to change this to HTML format in the future

    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Create an object and as you loop through the rows use email addresses as the properties and every time you encounter a new row ask if there is a property with that email address with hasOwnProperty if there is not then create an array with that property name and then push an object with the appropriate information in it and if there is already a property with that email address the push another object with appropriate information. At the end you can get an array of all of the properties with Object.keys() Outer loop loops through key inner loop loos through each property’s array.

Comment: And it seems that @Cooper has already answered an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740760/i-have-to-send-emails-taking-data-from-some-columns-if-the-email-is-repeated-i)

Comment: Thanks I have a short memory for some things.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you for that quick answer.  Worked a treat. Very much appreciated