# GSheets Script email for each row containing repeated data How to limit it to one row only?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

How to send an email once, if the row is repeated in the sheet where this is bringing it from?

If I put the MailApp.sendEmail part outside the loop and within a certain period of time the user changes two products' statuses, it only sends one email, containing one of the product's updated status. If I put MailApp.sendEmail within each condition met, it sends one email for each row.

Below is an image of what the sheet looks like:
[image]

There are usually multiple rows of data for one product and there should be only one email sent.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "Sim";

function sendEmails() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 48)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (rowData[18] === "Estudo" || rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento" || rowData[18] === "Aprovação" || rowData[18] === "Ativo" || rowData[18] === "Cancelado" || rowData[14] === "Descontinuado") {
    //var updateAsDate = new Date(rowData[13]);
    //var update = Utilities.formatDate(updateAsDate, "GMT" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );
    var produto = rowData[1];
    var emailTo = file.getOwner().getEmail();
    //var emailCC = file.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(",");
    var versao = rowData[2];
    var status = rowData[18];
    var lastUpdated = rowData[19];
    var lastUpdatedAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastUpdated, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + "hs";
    var usuario = rowData[20];
    var message =  "<HTML><BODY>"
        + "<P>Olá!"
        //+ "<br><br />"
        + "<P>O status do produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + ", foi atualizado para " + "<b>" +status +"</b>" + "."
        //+ "<brr /><br />"
        + "<br>Data da última atualização:  </b>" + lastUpdatedAsDate + "<br />"
        + "<br>Usuário: </b>" + usuario + "<br />"
        + "<br /><br />"    
        //+ "<br>Clique para explorar detalhes, ou para atualizar o status: </b>" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pL_AMKVtH4dGk1U7VWMeg590MxtNe7VY4gRqm_GhrM/edit?usp=sharing" + "<br />" 
        + "<br /><br />"  
        + "</HTML></BODY>";   
    var emailEstudo = rowData[42];    
    var emailDesenvolv = rowData[43];
    var emailAprov = rowData[44];
    var emailAtivo = rowData[45];
    var emailCancelado = rowData[46];
    var emailDescont = rowData[47];
    var subject = "O produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + " " +", mudou de status.";
    Logger.log(rowData[18]);
    if (emailDesenvolv != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 44).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     } else if(emailEstudo != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Estudo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 43).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }else if(emailAprov != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Aprovação") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 45).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }else if(emailAtivo != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Ativo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 46).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }else if(emailCancelado != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Cancelado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 47).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }else if(emailDescont != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Descontinuado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 48).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }
     }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    name: "P&D - PB",
    to: emailTo,
    //cc: emailCC,
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message
  });
    }
```

The intent is to send one email containing the product name, version and its current status. Therefore, although I have multiple rows with repeated data, the email would only need one row of data, but mark these repeated rows with EMAIL_SENT to avoid another email being sent later.

```
function SendEmail() {
  var mgrcol=4;
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var rg=sheet.getDataRange();
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var productList=[];
  var html='';
  for(var i=1;i<values.length;i++) {
    if(productList.indexOf(values[i][0])==-1 && productList.indexOf(values[i][2])==-1) {
      //mgrA.push(vA[i][3]);
      productList.push(values[i]); // Joga toda a linha que será usada pra dar os dados para o email.
    }
  }

  var productObj={}
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<values.length;j++) {
      if(productList[i]==values[j][0] && productList[i]==values[j][2]){
        if(productObj.hasOwnProperty(productList[i])) {
          productObj[productList[i]]+=Utilities.formatString('~~~%s<br />%s<br />%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }else{
          productObj[productList[i]]=Utilities.formatString('%s<br />%s<br />%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }                                               
      } 
    }
  }
  Logger.log(productList);
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    var tA=productObj[productList[i]].split('~~~'); //This is presenting the error
    var s='Status atualizado<br /></br />';
    for(var j=0;j<tA.length;j++) {
      s+=tA[j].toString() + '<br />'; 
    }
    s+='<hr widht="100" />';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(productList[i], 'User Names and Emails', null, {htmlBody:s})
    html+=Utilities.formatString('Email Recipient: <strong>%s</strong><br />',productList[i]) + s;//debug 
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);//debug
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Emails');//debug
}
```

Comment: Short answer: You filter the data before the mails are sent or you keep a lists of email sent and use a condition prevent sending another email to the same email address. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do in to run the emails in two passes.  First Pass just collects all of the data into an object of arrays the key of which is the email address.  The second pass you get the key from Object.keys() and then you loop through them collecting all of the data from the arrays in each key.

Comment: This is an example that is somewhat similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741922/7215091

Comment: Hi@Cooper, Read the content of the link more carefully and it really looks like my difficulty. I'll try that solution as soon as I can. Sorry I basically repeated my question, thinking you had makred it as duplicate a couple of hours ago.

Comment: If you have two rows with exactly the same content - maybe you want to remove duplicates from the sheet before proceeding wiht sending emails? Otherwise, please specify more in detail: Do you want to send one email contianing all rows that are not exact duplicates and are not marked as `EMAIL_SENT`? Do you run your funciton on time-driven trigger or onEdit?

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka, the intent is to send one email informing which product and version changed of status and mark this product and version's rows as EMAIL_SENT.

Comment: Hello @Cooper, I've trying to implement this one to my problem, but I can only get an identifier key by considering data from two columns (itemCode and version). Here, we have the email address. How would I go about considering these two columns as identifier key instead? Thanks!

Comment: I would use the email address as the property for the object which is an array of objects in the Object Store properties which are values from each row that you want to included in the email. At the end you’ll take the keys for the object which are going to be the emails and then you’ll loop over the array of each object to put all the data into each email and then you’ll send email one email for each group of rows

Comment: @Cooper, the email address to which the email will be sent is actually the spreadsheet's owner's. There's a column containing the email address of who changed that product...would that work? There is a lot for me to understand on object, concept wise.]

Comment: So what is it that is in common to these rows which are to be condensed to one row.

Comment: @Cooper, The product contains unique ingredients and their qty's. The other columns' rows contain repeated data to keep that sheet as a database.

Comment: Yes but how do you know which lines are compressed into one there must be some property that they all have in commom otherwise how would know which ones to condense into one row?

Comment: I'd consider the itemCode (Column A) and the itemVersion(Column C), @Cooper. Is that even possible for this purpose?

Comment: Okay that sounds good.  Then say that the property will be a combination of the two.  Let say we do it like this: `Utilities.formatString('%s-%s',data[i][0],data[i]2);`

Comment: If you want a tool to help you Copy and Redact CSV data that you can easily post into your SO questions. Here's a link: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/so-utilities/csv-utility.  Then I can perhaps give you a hand getting started.

Comment: @Cooper, just edited the question pointing where your solution in another case is presenting an error in this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215610/discussion-between-cooper-and-antonio-santos).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example to show you how to build arrays of rows that have common properties. I used the values of ColumnA and ColumnC to create the property because they match in the areas that I want to combine together.

Here's the code:

```
function makingObjects() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  const hA=vs.shift();
  let col={};
  let idx={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i;});
  let obj={pA:[]};
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    let prop=r[idx["COL1"]]+ "-" + r[idx["COL3"]];
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      obj[prop]=[];
      obj[prop].push({"COL2":r[idx["COL2"]],"COL4":r[idx["COL4"]],"COL5":r[idx["COL5"]],"COL6":r[idx["COL6"]]});
      obj.pA.push(prop);//I find easier just keep the properties here
    }else{
      obj[prop].push({"COL2":r[idx["COL2"]],"COL4":r[idx["COL4"]],"COL5":r[idx["COL5"]],"COL6":r[idx["COL6"]]});
    }
  });
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(obj)), "Rows Combined");//This will display a dialog showing how the rows are combined in separated arrays for each property.
  obj.pA.forEach(function(r,i){
    //Here you have to decide and how you want to combine them in each row.
  });
}
```

Here's the data from my spreadsheet:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6
1,1,a,1,1,1
1,2,a,2,2,2
2,3,b,3,3,3
2,4,b,4,4,4
3,5,c,5,5,5
3,6,c,6,6,6
4,7,d,7,7,7
4,8,d,8,8,8
5,9,e,9,9,9
5,10,e,10,10,10
6,11,f,11,11,11
6,12,f,12,12,12
7,13,g,13,13,13
7,14,g,14,14,14
8,15,h,15,15,15
8,16,h,16,16,16
9,17,i,17,17,17
9,18,i,18,18,18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've come up with:

```
  var produtoEmail = new Array();
  var versaoEmail = new Array();
  var statusEmail = new Array();
```

and then, within the if statements that qualify the row's data to be sent, it pushes the columns' data I want to the arrays above.

```
if (emailDesenvolv != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Desenvolvimento") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 44).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);      
        produtoEmail.push(data[i][1]);
        versaoEmail.push(data[i][2]); 
        statusEmail.push(data[i][18]);
```

Then, when writing the email, it gets only the first element of each array. 
I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way, given my poor technical understanding, but its solved my problem.

Appreciate the ones who helped me.

Cheers,