# Send one email to include one of the repeated columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I repurposed this code: [I have to send emails taking data from some columns. If the email is repeated I would like to send only one email with the values from the other cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740760/i-have-to-send-emails-taking-data-from-some-columns-if-the-email-is-repeated-i/54741922#54741922) but I need help on how to grab the two other columns with data without repeats.

My end result currently does send two different email messages (column B) with the listing of the Product details but the Username and TempPassword, it only takes the last row information and send to both recipients.

If this is considered as duplicate question, I apologize. I am not sure if I should piggy back on the original question. TIA!

[image]

Comment: Can you share a dummy sheet file for replication purposes? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "A" to "D" of a Spreadsheet.
- When the same email addresses are found in column "B", you want to send only one email using the email address.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the variables of `sheetName` and `subject`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const subject = "sample subject"; // Please set your expected subject of the email.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow < 2) return;
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:D" + lastRow).getDisplayValues();
  const obj = [...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[1], m.has(r[1]) ? [...m.get(r[1]), r] : [r]), new Map()).values()];
  const messages = obj.map(r => ({
    to: r[0][1],
    body: [
      "Your information:",
      `UserName: ${r[0][2]}`,
      `Password: ${r[0][3]}`,
      "",
      "Product:",
      ...r.map(([a]) => `- ${a}`),
    ].join("\n"),
    subject,
  }));
  messages.forEach(o => MailApp.sendEmail(o));
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "A2:D" of the sheet. And, the emails are sent using each email address.
- The format of the text body is from your question.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your showing sample Spreadsheet image. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

## Suggestion

> ***NOTE**: This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

You could try achieving your goal by using a combination of the JavaScript array methods [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp), [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp), and [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp). Here's an example of how you can do it.

## Script

```
function main() {
  let rawData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A:D').getValues().filter(row => row.some(cell => cell !== ''));

  processData(rawData).forEach(d => {
    let body =
      `<body>
        <p>[Body of the email]</p>

        <p>Your information:</p>
        <p>UserName: ${d[2]}</p>
        <p>Password: ${d[3]}</p>

        <p>Product:</p>
        <p>${d[1].split(', ').map(item => `•${item}`).join('<br>')}</p>
      </body>`;

    MailApp.sendEmail(d[0], 'User Names and Emails', null, { htmlBody: body });
    console.log(`Email sent to ${d[0]} \n${body}`);
  });
}

function processData(data) {
  const res = Object.values(data.slice(1).reduce((acc, row) => {
    const [product, emailAddress, userName, tempPassword] = row;
    if (!acc[emailAddress]) {
      acc[emailAddress] = { products: [product], emailAddress, userName, tempPassword };
    } else {
      acc[emailAddress].products.push(product);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})).map(({ products, emailAddress, ...rest }) => [emailAddress, products.join(', '), ...Object.values(rest)]);

  return res;
}
```

## Demo

- ***Sample Sheet***

[image]

- ***Sample result message***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. My question was not meant to ask for a new code. I was just thinking if there is a way to grab two details which are the username and password without repeating it based off from the other code. I do appreciate your response and time for providing more what I asked for. The "combination of the JavaScript array methods reduce, map, filter, and forEach" are new to me. I suppose this would work even if there are more than 10 columns, correct?  MailApp.sendEmail(d[0] ---> why is this d[0] if the recipient column is B? Sorry for dumb question here.

Comment: The function `processData` restructures and cleans your sheet data to this array structure `[emailAddress, products.join(', '), ...Object.values(rest)])` so that is why I used `d[0]`, since the index of the recipient email address returned by the `processData` is at index **0**. Thus, the design of this script is fixed from range `A:D`